# Multiple arguments in a PHP str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a PHP `str_replace` that replaces every hyphen `-` that comes right after a slash `/` by a non-breaking hyphen `&#809;`.

`str_replace( '/-', '/&#8209;', $input );`

I’d like to extend this `str_replace` with a second condition that says that also every hyphen that comes before a slash should also be replaced:

`str_replace( '-/', '&#8209;/', $input );`

How can I merge these to conditions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array of values with `str_replace`:

```
str_replace(array('/-', '-/'), array('/&#8209;', '&#8209;/'), $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
str_replace(['/-', '-/'], ['/&#8209;', '&#8209;/'], $input);
```